# Resources for beginners to develop with Zope 2

Tags: zope

I'm planning to write an application using Zope2; it's not going to be a CMS-ish application but let's say it's a rudimentary "accounting and finance" application.  From what I could understand so far (mostly by reading [Zope 2 Book](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/)), this is not an “instance-space” application and should be written in “Python packages” form.

I've been searching the net for many hours to find a tutorial or a guide on how to start such a project with no luck.  What I need, basically, is:

1. How to create the initial structure of the project?  I'm looking for some tool equivalent to [grokproject](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/grokproject) for Zope2.
2. A very simple example application so I can understand how things are put together.  I have absolutely no idea about this and I couldn't find any reference to this topic in [Zope 2 Book](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/).

I've already checked [Zope 2 Wiki](http://wiki.zope.org/zope2/Zope2Wiki), which hardly looks like a wiki BTW :-), but couldn't find anything useful for my case.

So I'd really appreciate if you could share anything useful in this regard with me.

TIA,

Comment: Found [Zope Developer's Guide](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/). I'm not sure if it's up-to-date as I have just started reading it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following, though bumpy, got me started:

- [Zope 2 Developer's Guide](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zdgbook/)
- [Zope 2 Book](http://docs.zope.org/zope2/zope2book/)
- [ZopeSkel](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ZopeSkel) for project creationg and doing the initial boilerplate
- Zope-ers' priceless help on StackOverflow :-)
- Not sure if I should recommend it but reading other products' code (specially SilvaForum and OFS.Folder) really helped me clear thing up in my mind.